# How does CFBridgingRelease act on objects retained in a Core Foundation container?

Tags: objective-c, core-foundation

I'm creating a `CFMutableArray` and populating it dynamically with `CFString`s.

1. If I'm bridging this `CFMutableArray` over as a `NSMutableArray` using `CFBridgingRelease`, what happens to its children?
2. When I access entries in the array afterwards, can I treat them as ARC-managed `NSString`s or should I do something fancy in the `CFArrayCallbacks` struct to handle that transfer automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I'm bridging this CFMutableArray over as a NSMutableArray using CFBridgingRelease, what happens to its children?

Likely, nothing.  Of course, this depends on what you've put into the CFArray you're casting.  If you have put C-types that aren't toll-free bridged to Objective-C types (some parts of CoreFoundation are still not bridged to anything yet), then the behavior of the resulting NS-type is undefined.

> When I access entries in the array afterwards, can I treat them as ARC-managed NSStrings or should I do something fancy in the CFArrayCallbacks struct to handle that transfer automatically?

You shouldn't need to do anything if you're dealing with bridged types in a bridged array.  The values contained within the array will already have been retained (so they should not get sent anymore `-retain`'s by the array), and should be fine to just pull out and use.